# Iptables fails to start after reboot

Tags: kernel, iptables, ufw

I have an issue with ufw/iptables and the kernel packages of my ubuntu machine The ufw service is not running because iptables is failing to start. Iptables fails because of a kernel issue. After reinstalling the kernel iptables and ufw work. Then after a reboot it fails again. I don't what to look at to fix this so it works again after a reboot.

Here is my system:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial

Any clue much appreciated. Thank you.

```
service ufw start
Job for ufw.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ufw.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status ufw.service
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-22 21:25:48 CEST; 23s ago
  Process: 26570 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26570 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 22 21:25:47 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[26570]: Error occurred at line: 1
Aug 22 21:25:47 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[26570]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[26570]: Problem loading ipv6 (skipping)
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[26570]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[26570]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[26570]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: ufw.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall.
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: ufw.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 21:25:48 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: ufw.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

ls /boot
abi-4.4.0-63-generic     config-4.4.0-64-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic  System.map-4.4.0-64-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
abi-4.4.0-64-generic     config-4.4.0-66-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic  System.map-4.4.0-66-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-67-generic
abi-4.4.0-66-generic     config-4.4.0-67-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-67-generic  System.map-4.4.0-67-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
abi-4.4.0-67-generic     config-4.4.0-70-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic  System.map-4.4.0-70-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
abi-4.4.0-70-generic     config-4.4.0-71-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic  System.map-4.4.0-71-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
abi-4.4.0-71-generic     config-4.4.0-72-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic  System.map-4.4.0-72-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
abi-4.4.0-72-generic     config-4.4.0-75-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic  System.map-4.4.0-75-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
abi-4.4.0-75-generic     config-4.4.0-79-generic      initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic  System.map-4.4.0-79-generic
abi-4.4.0-79-generic     grub                         lost+found                   vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
config-4.4.0-63-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic  System.map-4.4.0-63-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic

sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/21.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 312709 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic_4.4.0-79.100_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic (4.4.0-79.100) over (4.4.0-79.100) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic (4.4.0-79.100) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled
(4.4.0-79.100 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled
(4.4.0-79.100 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-79-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-79-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-70-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-67-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-67-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-66-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-66-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-63-generic
done

service ufw start
service ufw status
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-08-22 21:30:42 CEST; 6s ago
  Process: 3165 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3165 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 22 21:30:42 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
Aug 22 21:30:42 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.

reboot
service ufw status
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-22 21:32:56 CEST; 44s ago
  Process: 399 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 399 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Error occurred at line: 1
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Problem loading ipv6 (skipping)
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/after.rules'
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: ufw.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Uncomplicated firewall.
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: ufw.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net systemd[1]: ufw.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Did you see this line `Aug 22 21:32:56 mymachine.mydomain.net ufw-init[399]: Error occurred at line: 1`, did you alter your ufw and are we altering both `ufw` and `iptables` at the same time ?

Comment: Seems like a problem with iptables rules. Did you try running `iptables-restore -h` as error message suggested? Where did you get the idea it's kernel issue?

Comment: Please run `iptables-restore -h` as the error suggest so we can pinpoint the source of the error

Comment: I did a "ufw reset", but it doesn't help. iptables-restore -h will only save/restore configuration. It's now reset to default, but no better

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the iptables in the rc.local file?

You must tell the system to boot iptables.

Regards.

Comment: well it's not in rc.local.
But rc.local says 
# By default this script does nothing.